# authenticate and create a vm on azure using rest api

Tags: azure, authentication, virtual-machine

Can anyone kindly help me with the steps to authenticate and quick-create a ubuntu virtual machine on azure with a script using only the REST APIs. Kindly elaborate on the authentication process if possible.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

There is the Azure sample that can work for you:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-dotnet-rest-api-manage/blob/master/README.md

Please try it. As you did not specify, it is for .NET, but Azure-Samples repository has many different samples.